# What would you call it when an aunt complains about her nephew in front of his mom to needle her?

Tags: single-word-requests

Here is a situation:

Whenever a 2-year-old son does something wrong, his aunt always makes some remarks to her husband regarding that child's misbehavior and she does it deliberately in the presence of the child's mom obviously trying to needle her. For example, the mom told her child not to touch the remote control, but he just went ahead and grabbed it from the coffee table and accidentally dropped it on the floor - so the aunt right away told her husband, 'Look, he is so spoiled! Never listens to his parents!' Usually she doesn't do it loudly. She can't be accused of trying to start a fight with her sister-in-law (the child's mom) as she does have the right to tell her husband whatever she thinks, yet she never fails to do it audibly enough so that the child's mom could hear it.

What would you call the aunt's actions here? How would you describe what she is doing?

---

I am most interested in a noun or a verb: "What she is doing is called (noun)." or "She is simply (verb+ing)."

Examples:

- What she is doing is called mockery.
- She is simply ranting.

Comment: She is simply _being a b****_ . Seriously though, _passive aggressive_ is apt and all, but this kind of behavior, spreading negative energy for the sake of making other feel bad, needs a stronger and more judgmental word in my humble opinion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Passive aggressiveness is very apt. Provoking also comes to mind, depending on how we interpret her motives: she seems to be trying to provoke the child's mother, she is trying to get under her skin, she is trying to put her down. I am assuming that the mother of the child is her sister-in-law: she is trying to drive brother and sister apart by provoking the sister and setting her husband up against his sister by pushing him to join her in her provocations. She is a sower of discord, a bully, a manipulator. And, no, I have never had a sister-in-law perform such tricks of bullying and manipulation on me.

Comment: WOW!!! Thank you, Cerberus!!! I especially like "trying to get under her skin". Very graphic!!! :) Is it like though she is really trying to provoke her sister-in-law, I still can't say that she is being provocative, because "provocative" has some sexual connotation?

Comment: @Brilliant: While *provocative* can still mean "causing anger or irritation", I think *provoking* is the better adjective, because, as you say, *provocative* is now mostly used for "causing sexual excitement". Incidentally, do you actually know this aunt?

Comment: @Cerberus: Yes, I know her, but the story presented here is deliberately overstretched and has many made-up elements added to it as my focus here was more on how to describe this particular behavior in English, rather than on getting any consultation help :)

Comment: @Brilliant: Haha, I see. Well, good luck with her. By the way, *provocative* is also often used to describe modern art that supposedly provokes emotions in people.

Comment: @Cerberus: Is it only about paintings or any kind of modern art? For example, is movie-making included?

Comment: @Brilliant: Yes, but for this adjective to be used, it is a requirement that the creator of the film or other work of art is viewed by the speaker or writer as part of the typical circles of modern art, where concept is more important than technique or aesthetics. Generally, the more static and conceptual the work, the more chance that it will be called provocative, so films are less likely to be so called than, say, a monochrome jumble of rags or a peanut-butter floor, which happens to be on exhibition here right now in a near-by museum. Eh, what was I talking about?

Comment: @Cerberus: :) :) Well, I got the point. Some of these "jumbles of rags" and "peanut-butter floors" do provoke a lot emotions in me, albeit not that kind of emotions that the authors would probably mean to provoke. :)

Comment: @Brilliant: Haha, very well put!

Comment: I disagree that this is passive-aggressive.  Passive-aggressive people are not this blunt.  A passive-aggressive person would say something more like "Boys are so hard to raise, aren't they?"

Comment: +1 for the other things more than for passive-aggressive

Answer (score 15):

To describe the aunt’s behaviour as “passive aggressive” smacks a little of pseudo-psychiatry.

More commonly one might say she is being [**snide**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/snide):

> ***adjective*** Derogatory or mocking in an indirect way: *snide remarks about my mother*

Comment: Thank you, Brian. Is "snide" a common word in English?

Comment: Well, it's not something I find myself using every day, but I wouldn't say it's rare or obscure, either.

Comment: @brilliant yes, it's common to say "making snide comments"

Comment: Added the definition to show how perfect this really is. The example comment nails it.

Answer (score 7):

I'd say it's a form of passive aggressiveness. She doesn't complain directly to the person she's complaining about--she complains to someone else in her presence. As you put it, "she can't be accused of starting a fight." That's one of the passive aggressive traits: Being argumentative or otherwise behaving badly, but with some kind of deniability built into the process so she can deny the aggressive behavior.

This is far from the only trait of passive aggressive behavior, but it is a type.

Comment: Thank you Bikeboy39!!! Is "passive aggressiveness" a kind of idiom in English?

Comment: @brilliant: It is a pretty common term, I'd say, but it's also a recognized personality disorder when the behaviors are extreme. And as usual, the way it's commonly used isn't exactly the way it's defined as a psychological disorder. There's similarity, though.

Answer (score 7):

I can't accept passive-aggressive as an answer (though I've not down-voted) because it does **not** mean "indirect complaints" (the behaviour you describe) but rather it means *passive negativity, sometimes obstructionism*, which is something else altogether.

I suggest this behaviour is better described as ***needling***, where the aunt is goading and  provocative.  Needling is an informal word, but a good fit for this situation.

Comment: Since I received this answer, I've used "She's been passive aggressive" quite a few times in my conversations with native English speakers, and almost always could notice some shadow of confusion on their faces. However, when I switched to "She's been trying to needle..." they seemed to be okay with that.

Comment: @brilliant: You must be speaking of her the whole time! She must be horrible...

Comment: @Cerberus - :) Well, she's been especially "disturbing" lately :)

Answer (score 2):

The aunt is a [shit-stirrer](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/shit-stirrer): *one who makes trouble for others...by making known facts that they would prefer to keep secret*.

The shortened "cleaner" version **stirrer** is commonly used too. For the action itself, **shit-stirring** can be toned down to **stirring things up**.

This metaphoric "stirring" is so common that even more oblique references occur in things like..

> [...for Annina's sake, I expect you to hold that sharp tongue and put away your wooden spoon!](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=S_DvXzYjcykC&pg=PA111&dq=%22your%20wooden%20spoon%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YNKiUPzkG8iD4gTglIDwAg&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22your%20wooden%20spoon%22&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

[**Obnoxious**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obnoxious) comes to mind.

The fact that it is not directly addressed to the sister-in-law, but yet still audible by her seems clearly an attempt to offend/[annoy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obnoxious) her.

Comment: So, could I say that she is offending or she is annoying the child's mom?

Comment: @brillant: this is clearly an adult's game: she offends mainly the mom, not so much the child.

Comment: So, "offend" would be the right word here, right? Do you think "mind games" would also fit in or that would be too soft?

Comment: @brillant: "offensive" would be adequate. But "mind games" could apply even though it could very well be too sophisticated. Basically, she is simply **rude** to her sister-in-law.

Comment: @brilliant, @VonC: With respect, I think this is not the best answer. *Obnoxious* is a judgement of the behaviour, not a neutral description of it, any more than *engrossing* is a literary genre. *Passive aggressive* is a more specific and more objective description here.

Comment: @rahul: I agree and I have upvoted that proposition.

Answer (score 1):

The aunt is frustrated and instead of complaining directly to the parents she is complaining to someone else loudly to show her dissapproval.  It is pretty common and lately this behavior has been labled passive agressive to show the indirect, yet confrontational manner.

If the parent does not like the aunt saying mean things about her and her son in front of her, she must either confront the aunt directly, or indirectly to another relative that is sure to get back to the aunt.

This is why passive aggressive aunts often do not get invited places making them even more upset about being slighted and even nastier.  A vicious cycle.

Comment: This is not an answer; its really a comment

Answer (score 1):

How about *critical*? Negative? *Passively critical*, perhaps?

Comment: please expand your answer to include an explanation as to why any of these are good choices. The best way would be to give example sentences.

Answer (score 0):

I would characterize the aunt as being PROVOCATIVE. Essentially, she is trying to provoke the mother to pay more attention to her child by "calling out" the child's misbehavior. You can call her "snide," but in a sense, she is trying to be "tactful" by directing her remarks to her husband, rather than directly to the child's mother.

Comment: Per comments on @Cerberus's answer, the problem with *provocative* is the sexual connotations. That's why people sometimes use the word *provoking* for this particular behaviour.

Comment: @fumblefingers: That probably wasn't the case "originally." Perhaps it is true today. But I'd certain accept provoking as a reasonable synonym.

Comment: Well, [here's](http://books.google.com/books?id=DsQVAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA541&dq=%22provocative%22&hl=en&ei=IbgpTsD_DdO48gPV2MDwCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CDMQ6AEwATgU#v=onepage&q=%22provocative%22&f=false) an 1861 dictionary definition that says *tending to awaken or excite appetite or passion; exciting, stimulating.* So it's been that way for quite a while, even if the strong connotation with sexuality wasn't likely to be explicitly mentioned back then.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion I would say that the aunt is being overreactive. Seriously, what does 2-year old know about anything? Anyone getting upset about an infant's action is slightly... disturbing.

Comment: this is not Parenting.SE, where expectations on child-development are on-topic.  The OP is asking for a word.

Answer (score 0):

The polite word for what she is doing is  [**rebuke**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/rebuke):

> *verb*
>   **1.**
>   express sharp disapproval or criticism of (someone) because of their behavior or actions.

---

Another interpretation is that the aunt's actions are fine: she cannot rebuke the mom because it is not her blood-family, but she can rebuke the dad; the child is out of order and the parents need support from peers to ensure they raise the child well.  To do this, the aunt *rebukes*.

Comment: But doesn't rebuking implies first of all expressing disapproval directly to the person that deserves that rebuke? In my case, however, she is making this indirectly, she is telling this to her husband, however, she's doing this audibly enough so that the person that is being rebuked can also hear that. On the other hand, she can always say that she isn't telling that person a word - all the words she says "are addressed to her husband". So, it's a kind of rebuke, but in a quite a subtle format, so to say. Describing it just as rebuking would seem to be too general to me.

Comment: No no. The aunt is rebuking the child's father. It is clear to the aunt that the sister-in-law (child's mom) is performing what she seeing as a quality standard of parenthood. The aunt would expect the same civility regarding her own parenting standards. Since the brother is blood she has all force available to her to question the judgment of *his* parenting style, since the aunt and father were raised together under the same standard of their parents - which is clearly better that the mother was exposed.

Comment: It's thus the father's responsibility to parent better, so he gets the rebuke. The mother feels insulted because her judgement is being questioned, but this is unecessary. The mom is angry because she lacks the courage to stand up for the wisdom of her parenting style.

Comment: @brilliant Consider that, in one regard, there really is no word for this, because the actions of the aunt are directed at the father, not the mother, regardless of whether she chooses not to criticize / rebuke privately.  Since most are not this direct, the aunt will be negatively characterized by her peers.  If the aunt ***is*** intending to speak with the mom through the dad, we could probably use a word that is founded upon the judgement of a personal flaw. I.E. *snide*

Comment: "The aunt is rebuking the child's father" - The child's father is not present in my example. The aunt's husband is not the child's father. The aunt's husband is the brother of the child's mom.

Comment: "If the aunt is intending to speak with the mom through the dad" - Yes, she is. That was the whole point in my example.

Comment: Oh. Then **"snide"** is the word.  This woman may be right, insofar as proper parenting, but she is squarely in the *bitch* realm with the unmannerly way she goes about it.  If the in-laws are that uncouth in her eyes, she has the option to not associate with that company.

Comment: @brilliant also remember that this is the treatment that she expects for herself, so the mother here can use the same speaking-strategy when she sees the aunt do something improper.  She will either open up to the communication form she desires, or she will shut up with the nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Consider ***trolling***.

[Oxford Dictionaries says](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/troll):

> make a deliberately offensive or provocative online posting with the aim of upsetting someone or eliciting an angry response from them.

[Urban Dictionary says](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Trolling):

> Being a prick on the internet because you can. Typically unleashing one or more cynical or sarcastic remarks on an innocent by-stander, because it's the internet and, hey, you can.